# Archimesh Rail Window Apparently not set as Parent structure

Tags: archimesh-add-on

In the tutorial I'm following the person is able to move the rail window when created.  To me it looks like the newly created window is just in a group.  It's parts move or get left behind when I try to reposition it.  I think I get that it needs to be parented with keep transform, but I don't get why my newly created window is not working like that already.  It is only partially parented, with most not.  Working with Blender 3.0.0

Comment: What did you try to move exactly? The handles are parented to the windows, they and the window sill are parented to the frame, the hole controller and frame are parented to an empty called Window_Group. So if you want to move the complete window, you have to move the empty. Of course some things are only "partially" parented. For example, if you want to push open a window, the frame must not be parented to it otherwise you would move it with the window. But the handle for example needs to be moved with the window - so it doesn't make sense if it would be parented to the empty directly.

Comment: I try to move the window group object and they all move but at different rates.  So it separates weirdly when I try to move in any direction.

Comment: Did you scale some/all components? Are all transformations applied? For me everything works as expected... maybe you should upload a file to show what's happening.

Comment: I tried moving the window immediately after creating it.  [Blender Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lMbUPsCoX1hd9p_GHSMMYizMD49fKeZl/view?usp=sharing)  Also I upgraded to 3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *Proportional Editing* enabled. This means, depending on the size of the circle of influence, other objects within this circle will be moved as well but according to the influence range only to a certain percentage of the original movement - which works against the parent, because moving only the parent forces the children to move along. But if you move a child directly it will be independent from its parent. That's why the *Proportional Editing* separates the objects. You can either click on it to disable or use the hotkey <kbd>O</kbd> to toggle it on/off.

[image: proportional editing]

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure when I turned that on.  It was just a new project.

Comment: @Dan You might consider accepting the answer then.

Comment: By the way, if it was a new project: maybe _Proportional Editing_ was enabled from the beginning on? Did you check your startup file i.e. how the setting is if you open a new project? Because options like this will be saved with the startup file.